# How can I implement similar to the web query feature in Excel in java?

Tags: java

I'm new here and I hope I'm not asking something which has already been answered. I have searched everywhere but am yet to discover an adequate answer.

My objective is fairly simple: I want to create a program which will stream the live gold and silver rates from: [this website](http://www.24hgold.com/english/gold_silver_prices_charts.aspx?money=GBPound)

How would I be able to pinpoint the values that I want to download? Currently, I have managed to implement this using Microsoft Excel's web query feature wherein I am able to select a table from the webpage. However, I want to make it a standalone application.

By the way, I need to retrieve the rates to perform a calculation which is then displayed to the user.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas on how this can be achieved.

Comment: You want your application to update data every second or a little time  lapse will work.?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I want it to update every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to `scrape` or `parse` the data from your website. For that take a look at [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)  html parsers.

You can use `XPath` with htmlcleaner to pinpoint the data.Here is a nice example [Xpath Example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/using-xpath-and-html-cleaner-to-parse-html-xml/).

You can use firefox's `firebug` extension to get the xpath of an element. But your xpath is going to be very huge, by the look of the website you mentioned.

Than you have to execute the code at specified interval of your choice.

And if there is `javascript` in play than you have to execute the javascript running behind the page using your java code.

Try using `Rhino` from Mozilla and using its integration libraries or by using the JDK 1.6 `ScriptEngine` facility.

For `ScriptEngine` Example take a look here- http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/

> In, short take a look at `html parsers` to parse the content of your page.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Looks like I need to do a lot of research. I was hoping it was going to be a simple task :(

Comment: If you decide to use `htmlcleaner` take a look here http://pastebin.com/tCMBsPWg.

Comment: Thanks. I would have given you a vote up but I don't have enough reps.